# Can't pipe in bash's "mapfile" ... but why?

Tags: bash

I just want to get all the files in a certain directory into a bash array (assuming that none of the files have a newline in the name):

So:

```
myarr=()
find . -maxdepth 1  -name "mysqldump*" | mapfile -t myarr; echo "${myarr[@]}"
```

Empty result!

If I do the roundabout way of using a file, temporary or otherwise:

```
myarr=()
find . -maxdepth 1  -name "mysqldump*" > X
mapfile -t myarray < X
echo "${myarray[@]}"
```

Result!

But why doesn't `mapfile` read properly from a pipe?

Comment: Similar on unix.SE: [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373)

Comment: Excellent answers all around, thank you everyone. Interesting how the execution strategy of the pipeline (each part running in a spearate process) leaks "upwards" and modifies the apparent meaning of the code, basically silently putting "local" in front of every variable appearing in the pipe. In a language that is something other than crazy glue for other programs, that would be bug, hopefully.

Comment: If you give the code to [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), you get warnings: [SC2030](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2030): _"Modification of var is local (to subshell caused by pipeline)"_ and [SC2031](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2031): _"var was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost."_. Excellent.

Comment: Why using `find` and `mapfile` here at all and not just simply `myarr=(mysqldump*)`? This will even work with filennames with spaces and newlines.

Comment: @BlackJack What's on the RHS? An expression that is expanded an array to the files in the current working directory matching the regex? Bash really has weird, weird features. Actually, I want to use `find` to apply additional criteria, e.g. only directories, and only those older than D days, so the additional fexibility makes me prefer `find`.

Comment: On the RHS is an array ”literal” with the elements between the parenthesis.  For instance `X=(a b 'c d')` creates an array with three elements `a`, `b`, and `c d`. Bash performs word splitting and globbing on the content between the parenthesis.

Comment: Just noticed that one has to turn `nullglob` option on (`shopt -s nullglob`) on for `myarr=(mysqldump*)` to not end up with the array `('mysqldump*')` in case no files match.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [`man 1 bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

Such subshells inherit variables from the main shell but they are independent. This means `mapfile` in your original command operates on its own `myarr`. Then `echo` (being outside the pipe) prints empty `myarr` (which is the main shell's `myarr`).

This command works differently:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "mysqldump*" | { mapfile -t myarr; echo "${myarr[@]}"; }
```

In this case `mapfile` and `echo` operate on the same `myarr` (which is not the main shell's `myarr`).

To change the main shell's `myarr` you have to run `mapfile` in the main shell exactly. Example:

```
myarr=()
mapfile -t myarr < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "mysqldump*")
echo "${myarr[@]}"
```

Comment: Added the link to "process substituion" as given in Attie's response, in case a visitor has a TL;DR moment.

Comment: [Here is my demo using a herestring (`<<<`).](https://superuser.com/a/1706858/425838)

Answer (score 11):

Bash runs the commands of a pipeline in a subshell environment, so any variable assignments etc. that take place within it aren't visible to the rest of the shell.

Dash (Debian's `/bin/sh`) as well as busybox's `sh` are similar, while zsh and ksh
run the last part in the main shell. In Bash, you can use `shopt -s lastpipe` to do the same, but it only works when job control is disabled, so not in interactive shells by default.

So:

```
$ bash -c 'x=a; echo b | read x; echo $x'
a
$ bash -c 'shopt -s lastpipe; x=a; echo b | read x; echo $x'
b
```

<sub>(`read` and `mapfile` have the same issue.)</sub>

Alternatively (and [as mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/1348954/600133) by Attie), use [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Process_Substitution), which works like a generalized pipe, and is supported in Bash, ksh and zsh.

```
$ bash -c 'x=a; read x < <(echo b); echo $x'
b
```

POSIX leaves it unspecified if the parts of a pipeline run in subshells or not, so it can't really be said that any of the shells would be "wrong" in this.

Comment: If you disable bash's job control you can use lastpipe in an interactive shell, too : `set +m; shopt -s lastpipe; x=a; echo b | read x; echo $x; set -m`

Comment: @Cyrus, ah right, I'd forgotten the details, thanks

Answer (score 9):

As Kamil has pointed out, each element in the pipeline is a separate process.

You can use the following [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to get `find` to run in a different process, with the `mapfile` invocation remaining in your current interpreter, allowing access to `myarr` afterwards:

```
myarr=()
mapfile -t myarr < <( find . -maxdepth 1  -name "mysqldump*" )
echo "${myarr[@]}"
```

`b < <( a )` will act similarly to `a | b` in terms of how the pipeline is wired - the difference is that `b` is executed "*here*".

Answer (score 1):

If we use:

```
myarr=()
mapfile -t myarr < <( find . -maxdepth 1  -name "mysqldump*" )
echo "${myarr[@]}"
```

`${myarr[@]}` is not lost but `$?` of `<(find..)` is lost

If we use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "mysqldump*" | mapfile -t myarr
```

`${myarr[@]}` is lost but `$?` of `find` is not lost

if we use

```
shopt -s lastpipe
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "mysqldump*" | mapfile -t myarr
```

`${myarr[@]}` is not lost, `$?` of `find` is not lost but you need to disable `bash job control (set +m)`

if we use something like this

```
line=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "mysqldump*"); rc=$?; mapfile -d '\n' myarr <<< "$line"
```

`${myarr[@]}` is not lost, `$?` of find is not lost, `bash job control (set -m)` does not need to be disabled ... but you you can't use `\0` null byte as delimiter (`find ... -print0 | mapfile -d '' ...`)

The only way I have found come from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072044/process-substitution-and-exit-codes and need bash 4.4.x

```
exec {psfd}< <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "mysqldump*" -print0); procsub_pid=$!
mapfile -d '\0' myarr <&$psfd
exec {psfd}<&-
wait "$procsub_pid"
echo $?
echo "${myarr[@]}"
```

`${myarr[@]}` is not lost, `$?` of `find` is not lost, `bash job control (set -m)` does not need to be disabled and `\0` null byte can be used as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why*, per se, but looking at [`shellcheck` SC2206: Quote to prevent word splitting/globbing, or split robustly with `mapfile` or `read -a`.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206), I can see *how* to make your example work: use a herestring (`<<<`), like this:

> ```
> # For bash
> mapfile -t array <<< "$var"
> ```

For your particular case, therefore, do this:

```bsh
# Capture all `find` output into a regular "indexed" bash array by using
# `mapfile` and a herestring (`<<<`)
mapfile -t array <<< "$(find . -maxdepth 1  -name "mysqldump*")"

# Print all elements at once in a big blob (this also demonstrates how
# to pass all elements in the array as arguments to another function)
echo "${array[@]}"

# OR, print all elements nicely, one element per line
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "  $element"
done

# OR, the same thing as just above but as a one-liner:
for element in "${array[@]}"; do echo "  $element"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I am presenting my solution.

I refer to items in the very usefull arcticle

cant-pipe-in-bashs-mapfile-but-why

in

superuser: /questions/1348948/

There the main goal is not only to store the filenames in the array, but to store each one line as an alement in the array.

This I have solved for me.

Here I present my current solution.
It is a full-featured script.

- the array filled by bash command mapfile, resp. readarray is not lost;
- $? of find and of mapfile are printed (of find to STDERR);
- bash job control (set -m) does not need to be disabled; thus the script can - without any preparatory work - be run out of "fc";
- the problems with the delimiter ascii null are avoided;

Remarks:

The script is in a debugging state:

lines are numbered with the index of the array;

before lines of a new file will begin, filename with complete directory entry is put into an element of the array and is printed;

framed with comment lines;

both, the directory entry and the framing lines have "## " at beginning of line;

thus can easily be parsed and removed;

```
# +++++

mapfile -t  WEarr  <<< "$(find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "WEx_08*"  -exec /usr/bin/printf "#%.0s" {1..70} \; -exec echo "" \; -exec echo -n "## " \; -exec ls -lad --time-style=long-iso \{\} \;  -exec /usr/bin/printf "#%.0s" {1..70} \; -exec echo "" \;   -exec cat \{\} \; ; WE_retcod_find=$?; echo "WE_retcod_find: ~$WE_retcod_find~" >&2)"

WE_retcod_mapfile=$?
echo "WE_retcod_mapfile: $WE_retcod_mapfile~"

WE_noe_WEarr=${#WEarr[@]}
echo "WE_noe_WEarr: ~$WE_noe_WEarr~"

# for WE_element in "${WEarr[@]}"; do 
#   echo "WE_element: ~$WE_element~"
# done

for ((i=0; $i<$WE_noe_WEarr; i++)); do
  echo "i: $i ;; ~${WEarr[$i]}~"
done 

# -----
```

## -.-

Comment: That's not an "article", that's this question and you didn't link it correctly. How does your answer solve the problem AND differ substantially from the answers already given?